# Low color depth while using X11 on a monitor

Tags: x11, colors, macintosh, monitors

I am running Mint on a Late 2012 Mac Mini. While running X (KDE, LMDE or openbox) I notice  a low color depth on My Dell S2209W monitor. I believe that the depth is not actually low as I can change the depth to 8, 16 and 24 bits and observe differences.

However, when I connect different monitors (another DELL and an Acer), the colours appear as expected. There is nothing wrong with my S2209W as colours are produced appropriately on OSX and on mint when connected to a different computer.

Is this an X11 configuration issue? Is there anything I can do to experience better colours on the S2209W?

My Kernel:
`Linux hostname-MacMini 3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 13:15:40 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`